# pydev incorrectly formats multi-line keyword arguments while code formatting

Tags: pydev

Pydev is incorrectly formatting multi line keyword arguments to a function, and putting spaces even though the preferences is keyword arguments without spaces, in the special case when its a keyword argument following a regular argument.

Am I missing something here? and should possible bug reports stay on stack overflow? Fabio?

E.g.

```
funktion_call(arg1, kwarg1 = abc)
```

is correctly formatted to (with the appropriate pydev settings) to:

```
funktion_call(arg1, kwarg1=abc)
```

However, if the function call goes multiline:

```
funktion_call(arg1, 
                  kwarg1=abc)
```

then it incorrectly treats the spaces as if it was an assignment and formats to:

```
funktion_call(arg1, 
                  kwarg1 = abc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I can't reproduce it in the latest PyDev version (which version are you using?)

If you can reproduce it reliably, please create a bug report in the PyDev sf tracker with the example to reproduce it.

Regarding where to report things, if you're in doubt if it's a bug or not, here is a good place to ask, but if you're certain it's a bug, it should be reported directly to the PyDev sf tracker.

Comment: Fabio, I'm using Pydev 2.5.0.2012031515 (bundled with Aptana). I don't think there is a way of just updating Pydev? if you have the Aptana plugin installed as well?

Comment: I can definitely reproduce the problem with this code snippet...you can paste it as it into a .py file in eclipse..if you put a space after the keyword variable b by mistake, then it'll space it around the = and you can't get rid of it.

inline `
def function(a, b=None):
    pass

function(a=1231,
         b = 'asrtasr')`

Comment: This bug is already reported in the Pydev SF tracker as ID: [3460899](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3460899&group_id=85796&atid=577329)

Comment: Should be fixed for 2.6.0. Please grab the nightly build to test it.

Comment: I've 2.7.1 and it isn't fixed

Comment: Well, with that exact same case I can't really reproduce it... so, after the funding at http://igg.me/at/liclipse goes through, please report that as a bug (in the tracker that'll be created -- so, please buffer the request for now until the tracker is up).